# Electron Updater download-progress Event no getting called

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I´d like to show a progressbar inside my Electron App while an update gets downloaded. So, I´ve adjusted the example code from the electron-builder updater docs to my needs.

The following is an excerpt from my main.ts:

```
function sendStatusToWindow(updateState: UpdateState) {
  log.info(updateState);
  win.webContents.send('message', updateState);
}

autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
  sendStatusToWindow({ status: 'checking' });
});

autoUpdater.on('update-available', (info) => {
  sendStatusToWindow({ status: 'update-available' });
});

autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', (info) => {
  sendStatusToWindow({ status: 'current' });
});

autoUpdater.on('error', (err) => {
  sendStatusToWindow({ status: 'error', error: err });
});

autoUpdater.on('download-progress', (progressObj) => {
  log.info(progressObj);
  sendStatusToWindow({
    status: 'downloading',
    download: {
      bytesPerSecond: progressObj.bytesPerSecond,
      percent: progressObj.percent,
      transferred: progressObj.transferred,
      total: progressObj.total
    }
  });
});

autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (info) => {
  sendStatusToWindow({ status: 'completed' });
});
```

And my electron-builder.json:

```
  "win": {
    "icon": "dist",
    "target": ["NSIS"],
    "publish": ["github"]
  }
```

All events are getting called with the exception of `download-progress`
Is there anything I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the following?

```
    if (this.isDev) {
         this._autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
     } else {
        this._autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
     }
```

In dev mode the checkForUpdatesAndNotify does not trigger anything.  That only works when it is packed.  If you call checkForUpdates while in dev mode (electron-is-dev) then you should get the download events.

Comment: The issue also happens after the app is packed (via electron builder). In that case the development flag should be 0.